# Create absolute link with specific value of cell in table view

Tags: grafana

I want to render a absolute link in table from value of cell but I got a relative link instead.
[image]

Here is my configuration:
[image]

What I got when click on cell:
http://10.93.9.209:3000/http%3A%2F%2F10.131.227.253%2Fjob%2FPerformance%20Testing%20Pipeline%2Fjob%2Fstable%2F21%2F

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a change introduced in one of the new Grafana versions. If you want an absolute URL, you must use `${__cell:raw}` instead of `${__cell}`. [Reference](https://github.com/grafana/grafana/issues/12560)

Answer (score 7):

In Grafana 7 (new table panel) it's `${__data.fields[2]}` where number is column index.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to reference another column when clicking:

This is possible, I am using 9.1.7 and originally used the old table; however, after migrating noticed the same issue. That said, I found a way to make this work:

1. Add the ID column that you want to hide; example simID
2. If the column is the first column, say 0; then use:
   var-whatever=${__data.fields[0]}
3. Now, override the column, field with name: simID Add option ‘Hide in Table’ and turn on
4. I also had to format the number, e.g. remove decimals & set unit to standard

Hope that helps someone… took me a good 2 hours to figure.

Btw, it also works on graphs and you do not have to hide; aka reference your original query in the datasource and add a data link with the same options.

Answer (score 0):

What result do you get if you try `$__cell_2`?

Answer (score 0):

The syntax above no longer works. The value is now `${__value:raw}`

Answer (score 0):

$__cell_2 above solution worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

With the new table panel introduced in Grafana either ${__cell} or ${__cell:raw} do not work for this now.
You must use ${__value:raw}